# Why is my Ipad screen black but still makes sound?

Tags: ipad

So, I dropped my ipad. The screen goes black and it still makes sound, and when i click the home botton and the power botton it makes the screenshot sound. Also the screen lights up a little bit  So why is my screen black? And how do i fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the display/backlight is defective. You can try restoring your device with iTunes to rule out a software issue.

Comment: Will you be able to give me step by step instructions on what to do? I mean I know what you are saying but it would make me feel better if I knew that their was instructions there/

Comment: Here's a description from the apple page. https://support.apple.com/HT201252